# Why does my UIView.Transition not work unless wrapped in a UIView.Animate block?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimationtransition

I am using a UIView.transition to flip a card over.

While troubleshooting it not working, I stumbled upon a way to make it work - but I have no idea why.  I am hoping that someone can look at the two code blocks below and help me understand why one works and the other doesn't.  It seems very strange to me.

First, here is the code block that actually works.  The card flip is visually flawless.

> ```
> UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.01) {
>     imageView.alpha = 1.0
>     imageView.layoutIfNeeded()       // Works with and without this layoutIfNeeded()
> } completion: { (true) in
>     UIView.transition(with: imageView, duration: 1.2, options: animation) {
>         imageView.image = endingImage
>         imageView.layoutIfNeeded()   // Works with and without this layoutIfNeeded()
>     } completion: { (true) in
>         if self.dealTicketState.isTicketFaceUp == true { self.faceDownView.alpha = 0.0 } else { self.faceDownView.alpha = 1.0 }
>         UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.01) {
>             self.coveringLabel.backgroundColor = .clear
>             self.coveringLabel.layoutIfNeeded()
>             imageView.removeFromSuperview()
>             self.tickNumLabel.alpha = originalTicketNumAlpha
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

But I don't understand why I seem to need to wrap the UIView.transition() into the completion handler of a call to UIView.animate() in order for the flip animation to work.
*(Note:  If I pull the "imageView.alpha = 1.0" out of the animate() block and place it immediately BEFORE calling UIView.animate() - the flip animation does **not** occur (with or without the layoutIfNeeded() call).  It just toggles the images. *

Now, here is the code that I ***expected*** to work - but when I use this code instead of the above code, there is no "flip" transition.  The card image just immediately toggles between the face up and face down image.  The "UIView.transition" call here is identical to the one in the above code.  The only difference here is that it's **NOT** wrapped into a 0.01 second UIView.animate completion block.

> ```
> imageView.alpha = 1.0
> imageView.layoutIfNeeded()
>
> UIView.transition(with: imageView, duration: 1.2, options: animation) {
>             imageView.image = endingImage
>             imageView.layoutIfNeeded()    // same behaviour with and without this line
> } completion: { (true) in
>     if self.dealTicketState.isTicketFaceUp == true { self.faceDownView.alpha = 0.0 } else { self.faceDownView.alpha = 1.0 }
>     UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.01) {
>         self.coveringLabel.backgroundColor = .clear
>         self.coveringLabel.layoutIfNeeded()
>         imageView.removeFromSuperview()
>         self.tickNumLabel.alpha = originalTicketNumAlpha
>     }
> }
> ```

This transition ends my flipTicket() function.  The code that precedes this transition is identical in both cases.  I wasn't going to include it because I don't think it's necessary to understand the problem - but then again - what do I know?  Here's the stuff that came before the above clips:

> ```
> func flipTicket() {
>     let originalTicketNumAlpha = self.tickNumLabel.alpha
>     self.tickNumLabel.alpha = 0.0
>     
>     let tempFaceDownImage:UIImage = self.dealTicketState.faceDownImage
>     let tempFaceUpImage:UIImage = getCurrentFaceUpImage()
>     var endingImage:UIImage = self.dealTicketState.faceDownImage
>     
>     let imageView = UIImageView()
>     imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
>     imageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
>     imageView.clipsToBounds = true
>     imageView.alpha = 0.0
>     
>     self.coveringLabel.alpha = 1.0
>     self.coveringLabel.backgroundColor = .black
>     self.coveringLabel.layoutIfNeeded()
>     
>     var animation:UIView.AnimationOptions = .transitionFlipFromLeft
>     
>     if faceDownView.alpha == 1.0 {
>         animation = .transitionFlipFromRight
>         imageView.image = tempFaceDownImage
>         endingImage = tempFaceUpImage
>     } else {
>         animation = .transitionFlipFromLeft
>         imageView.image = tempFaceUpImage
>     }
>     self.addSubview(imageView)
>     NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
>         imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor),
>         imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor),
>         imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor),
>         imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor),
>     ])
>     imageView.layoutIfNeeded()
> ```

Background:
This code is part of a custom UI control which represents a playing card.  It consists of several subviews.  The topmost subview was originally a UIImageView which held the image of the back of the card.  This let me simply toggle the alpha for that top view to display the card as either face up or face down.  And then I added one more topMost view to the control - a UILabel with "background = .clear" and attached a UITapGestureRecognizer to it.  When the control is tapped, this function which is meant to animate the flipping over of the card is called.

To construct the animation, I call the getCurrentFaceUp() function which temporarily sets the alpha of the card's faceDownView to 0 (so I can take a snapshot of the card underneath it as it is currently configured).  It returns a UIImage of the "face up" view of the card.  I already have a UIImage of the faceDown view.  These are the 2 images I need for the transition.

So...then I set the background color of that topMost UILabel to .black, create a new temporary UIImageView and place it on top of the existing control.  I set the temporary imageView to initially display whichever one of the 2 images is currently visible on the control.  And then I run the flip transition, change the configuration of the background control to match the new state, change the label background back to .clear and dispose of the temporary UIImageView.
(If there's a better way to accomplish this, I'm open to hearing it but the main purpose of this post is to understand why my code appears to be acting strangely.)

When I was looking for a way to animate a card flip, I found a YouTube video that demonstrated the UIView.transition() with the flip animation.  It did not require using a UIView.animate() wrapper in order to make it work - so I'm pretty certain that it's me that did something wrong -but I've spent hours testing variations and searching for someone else with this problem and I haven't been able to find the answer.

Thanks very much in advance to anybody that can help me understand what's going on here...

Comment: I don’t think it’s the layoutIfNeeded().  I tested it both with and without the calls to layoutIfNeeded() and it acts the same way  - that is - it works in the one example and it doesn’t work in the other (but both sets of code include the layoutIfNeeded() calls.  Also - the Apple docs state that you need to include layoutIfNeeded() at the end the animations block so it knows what to animate.

Comment: OK so it seems to be the setting of the `imageView.alpha` then? If you comment that out temporarily does that fix it?

Comment: @matt No, commenting out the ImageView.alpha=1.0 does not make the broken code work - but it does make the working code break.

Answer (score 1):

A little tough to tell (didn't try to actually run your code), but I think you may be doing more than you need to.

Take a look at this...

We'll start with two "Card View" subclasses - Front and Back (we'll "style" them in the next step):

```
class CardFrontView: UIView {
}
class CardBackView: UIView {
}
```

Then, a "Playing Card View" class, that contains a "Front" view (cyan) and a "Back" view (red). On init, we add the subviews and set the "Front" view hidden. On tap, we'll run the flip transition between the Front and Back views:

```
class PlayingCardView: UIView {
    
    let cardFront: CardFrontView = CardFrontView()
    let cardBack: CardBackView = CardBackView()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {

        // add both card views
        // constraining all 4 sides to self
        [cardFront, cardBack].forEach { v in
            addSubview(v)
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                v.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
                v.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
                v.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
                v.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
            ])
        }
        
        cardFront.backgroundColor = .cyan
        cardBack.backgroundColor = .red

        // start with cardFront hidden
        cardFront.isHidden = true
        
        // add a tap recognizer
        let t = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(flipMe))
        addGestureRecognizer(t)
        
    }
    
    @objc func flipMe() -> Void {
        // fromView is the one that is NOT hidden
        let fromView = cardBack.isHidden ? cardFront : cardBack

        // toView is the one that IS hidden
        let toView = cardBack.isHidden ? cardBack : cardFront

        // if we're going from back-to-front
        //  flip from left
        // else
        //  flip from right
        let direction: UIView.AnimationOptions = cardBack.isHidden ? .transitionFlipFromRight : .transitionFlipFromLeft
        
        UIView.transition(from: fromView,
                          to: toView,
                          duration: 0.5,
                          options: [direction, .showHideTransitionViews],
                          completion: { b in
                            // if we want to do something on completion
                          })
    }
    
}
```

and then here's a simple Controller example:

```
class FlipCardVC: UIViewController {
    
    let pCard: PlayingCardView = PlayingCardView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        pCard.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(pCard)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            pCard.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            pCard.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
            pCard.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0),
            pCard.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pCard.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.5),
        ])
        
    }
    
}
```

The result:

[image]

So, next step, we'll add a little styling to the Front and Back views -- no changes to the `PlayingCardView` functionality... just a couple new lines to set the styling...

Card Front View - with rounded corners, a border and labels at the corners and center:

```
class CardFrontView: UIView {
    
    var theLabels: [UILabel] = []
    
    var cardID: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            theLabels.forEach {
                $0.text = "\(cardID)"
            }
        }
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        
        for i in 1...5 {
            let v = UILabel()
            v.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 24.0)
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            addSubview(v)
            switch i {
            case 1:
                v.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 10.0).isActive = true
                v.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 16.0).isActive = true
            case 2:
                v.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 10.0).isActive = true
                v.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -16.0).isActive = true
            case 3:
                v.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -10.0).isActive = true
                v.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 16.0).isActive = true
            case 4:
                v.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -10.0).isActive = true
                v.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -16.0).isActive = true
            default:
                v.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true
                v.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
            }
            theLabels.append(v)
        }
        
        layer.cornerRadius = 6
        
        // border
        layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        
    }
    
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Card Back View - with rounded corners, a border and a cross-hatch pattern:

```
class CardBackView: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {

        layer.cornerRadius = 6
        
        // border
        layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        
        layer.masksToBounds = true
        
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        // simple cross-hatch pattern
        let hReplicatorLayer = CAReplicatorLayer()
        let vReplicatorLayer = CAReplicatorLayer()
        
        let line = CAShapeLayer()
        let pth = UIBezierPath()
        
        pth.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0))
        pth.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 20.0, y: 20.0))
        pth.move(to: CGPoint(x: 20.0, y: 0.0))
        pth.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 20.0))
        line.strokeColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
        line.lineWidth = 1
        line.path = pth.cgPath
        
        var instanceCount = Int((bounds.maxX + 0.0) / 20.0)
        hReplicatorLayer.instanceCount = instanceCount
        hReplicatorLayer.instanceTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(20, 0, 0)
        
        instanceCount = Int((bounds.maxY + 0.0) / 20.0)
        vReplicatorLayer.instanceCount = instanceCount
        vReplicatorLayer.instanceTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(0, 20, 0)
        
        hReplicatorLayer.addSublayer(line)
        vReplicatorLayer.addSublayer(hReplicatorLayer)
        layer.addSublayer(vReplicatorLayer)
    }

}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Playing Card View:

```
class PlayingCardView: UIView {

    var cardID: Int = 0 { didSet { cardFront.cardID = cardID } }

    let cardFront: CardFrontView = CardFrontView()
    let cardBack: CardBackView = CardBackView()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        
        // add both card views
        // constraining all 4 sides to self
        [cardFront, cardBack].forEach { v in
            addSubview(v)
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                v.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
                v.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
                v.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
                v.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
            ])
        }
        
        cardFront.backgroundColor = .white
        
        cardBack.backgroundColor = .red

        // start with cardFront hidden
        cardFront.isHidden = true
        
        // add a tap recognizer
        let t = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(flipMe))
        addGestureRecognizer(t)
        
    }
    
    @objc func flipMe() -> Void {
        // fromView is the one that is NOT hidden
        let fromView = cardBack.isHidden ? cardFront : cardBack
        
        // toView is the one that IS hidden
        let toView = cardBack.isHidden ? cardBack : cardFront
        
        // if we're going from back-to-front
        //  flip from left
        // else
        //  flip from right
        let direction: UIView.AnimationOptions = cardBack.isHidden ? .transitionFlipFromRight : .transitionFlipFromLeft
        
        UIView.transition(from: fromView,
                          to: toView,
                          duration: 0.5,
                          options: [direction, .showHideTransitionViews],
                          completion: { b in
                            // if we want to do something on completion
                          })
    }
    
}
```

and finally, the same Controller example:

```
class FlipCardVC: UIViewController {
    
    let pCard: PlayingCardView = PlayingCardView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        pCard.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(pCard)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            pCard.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            pCard.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
            pCard.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0),
            pCard.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pCard.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.5),
        ])
        
        pCard.cardID = 5
    }
    
}
```

and here's the new result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this detailed tutorial.  If I were starting from scratch, this is definitely the way I would have gone, however at this point, I have a working card that’s entirely self contained in a single class/file and splitting it into 3 files doesn’t buy me enough in benefits to redo it.  Your response is extremely useful and I thank you very much for it - but since it doesn’t address my main question, I don’t think I can mark it as the answer.  I particularly like the way you created the cross-hatch pattern for the back of the card!

Comment: @Jim - *"splitting it into 3 files"* is just for clarity... a single class certainly could do all of that. If you update your question with enough code to run it (without me having to guess at what `self.dealTicketState.isTicketFaceUp` is, how `coveringLabel` and `tickNumLabel` are laid-out, what `getCurrentFaceUpImage()` does, etc -- ideally a minimal example project), I'll take a look at it and see if I can tell you what's going wrong.